# How to set rewrite cond apache by Ip range

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have this rewrite cond in .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^195.16.40.50
```

How to set RewriteCond by ip range from 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.32.255

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This condition should match your ip range:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^195\.168\.([0-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2])\.[0-9]+$
```

Comment: fank you wery math and sorry for my English